# How do I get the equivalent of Set-DnsClientServerAddress in Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell

How do I set the DNS address for a network adapter programmatically in Windows Server 2008?  It looks like `Set-DnsClientServerAddress` isn't supported.

Comment: Does Server 2008 have powershell 2.0 or above installed on it? Did you try it after that was on there (Framework install and .net required to do so) I was always under the impression that powershell 4.0 was backward compatible through 2.0 so it should've worked. Someone feel free to chime in.

Comment: "Backward compatible" does not mean "New cmdlets work on old OSes". [`Set-DnsClientServerAddress`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj590768(v=wps.630).aspx) requires Server 2012 R2 or higher.

Comment: Check out http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/09/13/manage-dns-in-a-windows-environment-by-using-powershell.aspx

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to do this via PowerShell ([the docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj590768(v=wps.630).aspx) aren't explicit about this, but you can see Server 2008 is not listed at the top of the page), but you can use `netsh`:

```
netsh interface ip add dnsserver "Local Area Connection" 10.0.0.1
```

Comment: It's almost never impossible to do something in Powershell.  As you can access .net in powershell, you *could* use .net code in powershell to accomplish this goal.

Comment: It's possible, but there are no built in commands specifically for DNS in PowerShell on 2008.

Answer (score 3):

Since you asked for PowerShell, you can use WMI and set it via the `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` provider:

```
Get-WMIObject win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration
```

This will list the adapters you have, then you can select a specific one:

```
$adapter = Get-WMIObject win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "Index=X"
# or use PowerShell filtering
$adapter = Get-WMIObject win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object { $_.Index -eq X }
```

Then you use the `SetDNSServerSearchOrder()` method to to set the address(es):

```
$adapter.SetDNSServerSearchOrder("8.8.8.8")
# or a list
$dns_servers = "8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"
$adapter.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($dns_servers)
```

Bonus one-liner:

```
(gwmi win32_networkadapterconfiguration -Filter "index=x").SetDNSServerSearchOrder(@("8.8.8.8","8.8.4.4"))
```